# Protobuf-net serializer for NEventStore 3+

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net, cqrs, neventstore

Can anyone point me to a protobuf-net serializer for NEventStore 3.0?

I'm having trouble I think mainly due to the serialization in event store 3 wrapping the event body and headers in an EventMessage.

I'm not sure how to setup the custom serializer correctly.

Comment: I don't know anything about eventstore, but looking at the project page it says to include "cqrs" on questions - presumably the project owner(s) monitor that primarily. If I can help with any protobuf-net info, I will - but I'm not familiar with the eventstore API. However! it looks primarily a case of implementing the [`ISerialize`](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/blob/master/src/proj/EventStore/Serialization/ISerialize.cs) interface, which looks to be a direct fit for protobuf-net's API.

Comment: Hi Marc, yep cheers for adding the tag. Im sure Jonathon will spot the question, he's normally pretty good at replying on SO. This really does boil down to a protobuf-net question, rather than an ES3 question.

Comment: I'd go look at the source and tests for [one of] the other serialization mechanism(s) and see how that slots in.

Comment: @boz ultimately most of this relates to ES3 plumbing, but I'll meet you half way and say "it is both" :)

Comment: haha, sounds good marc. if you have a look at this gist - as you point out below - the actual wiring up of a custom serializer is simple. Im having trouble serializing the EventMessage object. https://gist.github.com/meboz/5322871

Comment: @boz and what does EventMessage look like? Note that you can configure protobuf-net at runtime of the type is outside of your control (attributes are easier, but either approach works)

Comment: @marc - this is the EventMessage from the Event Store. https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/blob/master/src/proj/EventStore/EventMessage.cs. I have a working version but needed to attribute the object. Id rather use your approach of configuring at runtime.

Comment: @boz the use of `object` in there makes it problematic. Do you know in advance what these values are? protobuf-net works best with predictable schema

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely untested guesswork based on a very brief glance at github, but it looks like you want to use the wire-up API to specify a custom serializer, for example:

```
var store = Wireup.Init()
    .UsingSqlPersistence("Name Of EventStore ConnectionString In Config File")
        .InitializeStorageEngine()
        .UsingCustomSerialization(mySerializer)
    ... etc
```

where `mySerializer` is an instance of a type that implements the `ISerialize` interface. It looks like this should work:

```
class ProtobufSerializer : EventStore.Serialization.ISerialize
{
    public void Serialize<T>(Stream output, T graph)
    {
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<T>(output, graph);
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(Stream input)
    {
        return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(input);
    }
}
```

(so obviously `mySerializer` here would be a `new ProtobufSerializer()`)

Comment: The only trick is that type information would somehow have to be embedded into the payload because multiple messages can be serialized as a block.  I'm not sure if protobuf-net supports that yet.

Comment: @Jonathan well it kinda does but for limited scenarios... I struggle to recommend it. However: there are sometimes ways around it more neatly with inheritance (which is fully supported) or a form to of union

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thanks for the feedback. Ive got a serializer working in a development environment, but i did need to add proto attributes to the EventMessage. Once I have a good working version, Ill post code.

Comment: @boz it should never be **necessary** to add attributes; everything can be configured at runtime when that is an issue - see `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`.